# Quicker way of doing this

Tags: php

I'm using PDO to get an array of relations from my DB.

```
$dbRelaties = $dbh->query("SELECT pkRelatieId,naam,email FROM relaties");
```

in another function i need to acces one specific row in this array. I've managed to do it like this:

```
$klant = array();
foreach($dbRelaties as $dbRelatie)
{
    if($dbRelatie["pkRelatieId"] == $relatie){ $klant = $dbRelatie; break; }
}
sendMail("Subject",$klant);
```

The above code works. But i'me looking for a neater solution and a quicker one, the above code is called in a function and that function is called inside a loop. So everytime it executes is has to loop through `$dbRelaties` to get the correct relation.

Can anyone set me in the right direction?

Comment: Do a new query with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @datasage so doing a new query is quicker than using the data that is already in my memory?

Comment: If your dataset is small, 10's to 100 rows, it might not matter very much. If your query is in the order of thousands of rows (or might grow to that size), you may be pulling back data you don't need, and searching will take more time.

Comment: It's either what @datasage says, or you have to create an additional data structure to index and sort your result set based on the `pkRelatieId` so that you can do a fast binary search to locate the desired item. This is called a database, and the search is called a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a PDO specific version of Marc B's answer.

Assuming a query was executed through PDO like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT pkRelatieId,naam,email FROM relaties";
$resultSet = $pdo->query($sql);
```

The results can be read into a PHP array using PDO's fetch method.

```
$dbRelaties = array();
while ($row = $resultSet->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $dbRelaties[$row['pkRelatieID']] = $row;
}
```

This can then be used to access values based on the PK of the row.

```
sendMail("Subject", $dbRelaties[$relatie]['naam']);
```

---

Furthermore. PDO lets you assign a default fetch mode to each PDO instance, and the PDOStatement class is Traversable, so that you don't actually have to call the fetch() method in a while loop to go through a result set.

If you were to do this to a PDO object before a query: *(Ideally only once right after creating the object.)*

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then you can use a foreach loop on the result set to get row arrays with field names, instead of using a while loop.

```
$dbRelaties = array();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $dbRelaties[$row['pkRelatieID']] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

assuming the `pk` means primary key, then

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $dbRelatie[$row['pkRelatieID']] = $row;
}
```

would produce an array keyed with your primary key field, so

```
$dbRelatie[$pk]['naam']
```

will give you that particular pk's naam value.

Comment: too fast for me :-) - and this is the way you will do it. Looking for a array key is pretty fast in PHP

Comment: @MarcB Well... http://php.net/en/mysql-connect Even the OP doesn't use it anymore

Comment: @KingCrunch: one would hope that the OP is smart enough to realize that a snippet answer is not going to work out-of-the-box...

Comment: Even if *he* is, @MarcB, there are a lot of programmers out there that don't yet realize the MySQL APi functions are deprecated. Using them as if they are still relevant all over the place certainly won't help the situation. - It's not hard to do `$dbh->fetch` instead.

Comment: @MarcB But another can come to the conclusion, that it is a good idea to use `ext/mysql`, when its (kind of) recommended in 2013 by one with 122k Rep ...

Comment: @MarcB maybe it's best if you edited your answer with a PDO solution.

Comment: @atli: at least mysql_*() has the virtual of being unmistakable. Which db library is the OP using? could be mysqli, could be PDO, could be something custom. I'm not going to write out a longwinded answer assuming PDO only to find out that the OP's `$dbh` is actually a flat text file and the db library is the equivalent of `$dbh = file('mydb.txt')`. So no, I'm not going to rewrite because of deprecation. PHP's got enough OTHER crap in it that should be removed long before mysql_*() comes up to the chopping block.

Comment: @MarcB The op uses PDO (it's mentioned in the very first sentence...). However, _both_ extensions have a `fetch()`-method

Comment: @Atli Correct, although i have already succesfully solved this with the PDO::fetch method in a while loop. Would you mind posting an answer on how to do that so that ohters can learn from it. I will accept that answer. Thanks.